# Run time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set- updating XML from Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vbscript

I am getting a Run time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set when i am trying to update and XML using Excel Vbscript

```
    Sub UpdateXML()
    Call fnUpdateXMLByTags
    End Sub

    Function fnUpdateXMLByTags()

    Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmldoc.Load "F:\XML\XML1.xml"
    oMsgId = "15544216089S01F15544100002396000002"
    Set nMsgId = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//AcctSwtchBtch/GrpHdr/MsgId")
    nMsgId.Text = oMsgId
    strResult = xmldoc.Save("F:\XML\XML1.xml")

    End Function
```

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: It is not highlighting the line

Comment: Are you coding in vba? If yes, please run the scirpt step-by-step (with F8) and tell us, where it failed

Comment: It is failing at nMsgId.Text = oMsgId

Comment: Does selectsinglenode there return a valid node? Add nMsgId to your watched values and watch its value, while the it is assigned via set.

Comment: Changed it to SelectNodes...and the value is coming correctly

Comment: in the line "nMsgId.Text = oMsgId" your variable nMsgId is a valid node and you are getting the same error?

Comment: Can you check the answer i have posted...i updated the code. it is not giving me any errors but it is not updating the XML.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have Set without a Dim:

```
Dim xmldoc As Object
Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
...
```

I am not sure about nMsgId type, so comment the final part from "Set nMsgId" and:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//AcctSwtchBtch/GrpHdr/MsgId"))
```

with the correct type you can create the right instance of nMsgId

Comment: They tagged the question VBScript not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

A function must return something. Example:

```
Function FileExists(FilePath As String, FileName As String) As Boolean

Dim CurrentDir As String
CurrentDir = CurDir ' Used to set the CurDir back to what it was

If FilePath <> "" Then ChDir FilePath

If Dir(FileName) <> "" Then
    FileExists = True
Else
    FileExists = False
End If
ChDir CurrentDir

End Function
```

I suggest changing it from a function to a sub.

Comment: This still doesnt work : 

         Sub UpdateXML()
     
         Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
        xmldoc.Load "F:\XML\XML1.xml"
        
               
        oMsgId = "15544216089S01F15544100002396000002"
               
        Set nMsgId = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//AcctSwtchBtch/GrpHdr/MsgId")
        
        'Set the text node with the new value
        nMsgId.Text = oMsgId
         
        strResult = xmldoc.Save("F:\XML\XML1.xml")
            
        End Sub

Comment: They tagged the question VBScript not VBA.